# click anchor tag located inside cell of htmltable using codedui

Tags: c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests

Trying to click anchor tag located inside a cell of htmltable. In my case when first tagname "TD" found then inside that first "TD" an anchor tab is always available which I want to click. Unable to do that.

My code is -

```
public void tableRead()
    {
        HtmlTable tableInPrg = new HtmlTable(goBrowser);
        tableInPrg.SearchProperties.Add("ID", "MainContent_DispatchSummaryUserControl3_girdDispatchSummary");
        UITestControlCollection rowcontrol = tableInPrg.Rows;

        int rowcount = 0;

        string[] colNames = tableInPrg.GetColumnNames();

        foreach (UITestControl item in rowcontrol)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            int colCount = 0;
            if (item is HtmlRow)
            {
                rowcount++;
                foreach (HtmlControl cell in item.GetChildren())
                {
                    if (cell.TagName.ToString() == "TD")
                    {
                        string txt = cell.InnerText.ToString(); // this text value is anchor tag's value

                        // want to click on the anchor tag but unable to code here

                        flag = true;
                        break; 
                    }
                    colCount++;
                }
                if(flag)
                {
                    break;
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?  I'm pretty sure you just need to do another search from the cell.

```
HtmlHyperlink aTag = new HtmlHyperlink(cell);
Mouse.Click(aTag);
```